# How to restore a previous Firefox session?

Tags: firefox, session

In Firefox 3.5.4 on Ubuntu 9.10 I have (of course) session saving (the built-in one) enabled.

I closed the main Firefox window, but the "Downloads" window was still open. And on reopen, it had forgotten about the previous tabs. This is annoying as hell, and yes, I should report (or check for) a bug. If I could stand [Bugzilla](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bugzilla), that is.  :P

I have the `sessionstore.js` file with this older session (scanning it with less showed many of the sites I know had been open). How do I get Firefox to use this session file?

I did try to remove sessionstore.* and copy the `sessionstore.js` (or .bak) to the profile folder. But that doesn't have any effect.

Answer (score 1):

The simple way is to go to menu Tools > Options (it may be different in Firefox for Ubuntu).

Then, General, choose "Show my windows and tabs from last time" (instead of "Show my home page"). It works properly (found in the article [Session Restore](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Session+Restore) at Mozilla). If not, you could try out another way.

There's an add-on for it, *[Session Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2324)*.

You could easily restore by using it.

Comment: Thanks for the "jumping to easy conclusions" and for the condescending tone.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with "[Tab Mix Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-mix-plus/)" extension. It's got a neat session management part built-in (you have to select it in the options of the extension.)